# Accessing Java default methods in a subinterface or implementation class

Tags: java, methods, interface, overriding, default

I understand if a class overrides a default method, you can access the default method in the following manner

```
interface IFoo {
    default void bar() {}
}

class MyClass implements IFoo {
    void bar() {}
    void ifoobar() {
        IFoo.super.bar();
    }
}
```

But what about the case where an interface overrides a default method?  Is the parent method available in any way?

```
interface IFoo {
    default void bar() {}
}

interface ISubFoo extends IFoo {
    // is IFoo.bar available anywhere in here?
    default void bar {}
} 

class MyClass implements ISubFoo {
    // is IFoo.bar available anywhere in here too?

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass mc = new MyClass();
        mc.bar(); // calls ISubFoo.bar
    }
}
```

The verbiage Java uses for default methods is similar to that for classes, otherwise it's confusing/misleading.  Subinterfaces "inherit" default methods, and can "overwrite" them.  So it seems IFoo.bar should be accessible somewhere.

Comment: No, there is no `super.super` in Java. You can never access a method that was overridden in the parent, regardless of wether it's a `class` or a `default` method on an `interface`.

Answer (score 2):

You can go one level up, so the `IFoo.bar()` is available in ISubFoo with `IFoo.super.bar()`.

```
interface IFoo {
    default void bar() {}
}

interface ISubFoo extends IFoo {
    // is IFoo.bar available anywhere in here?
    // Yes it is
    default void bar {
        IFoo.super.bar()
    }
} 

class MyClass implements ISubFoo {
    // is IFoo.bar available anywhere in here too?
    // Not it is not

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass mc = new MyClass();
        mc.bar(); // calls ISubFoo.bar
    }
}
```